# Confusing .funs argument to mutate_all in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I do not understand the .funs argument to mutate_all() in the dplyr package. In all likelihood the problem lies with me but i would like to understand what I am missing.

I often have to recode multiple variables, like sets of likert items.

The sample code below replicates the problem I often have, and my own solution, but to me my solution does not look like the help documentation. So what am I missing?

```
#Data
var1<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100, replace=T)
var2<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100, replace=T)
dat<-data.frame(var1, var2)
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
#As per help documentation
dat %>% 
mutate_all(., .funs(Recode(., "'A'=1"))) # This doesn't work, generates an error

#this works but the help documentation does not get you there in anyway, unless I am missing 
something. 
dat %>% 
mutate_all(., funs(Recode(., "'A'=1")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recent version of `dplyr`, `list` takes the place of `funs` i.e. wrapping with `list` instead of `funs`

```
library(dplyr) #v 0.8.3
library(car)
```

So, either

```
dat %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = ~Recode(., "'A' = 1")) %>%
  head(5)
#  var1 var2
#1    B    C
#2    B    C
#3    B    C
#4    B    1
#5    C    C
```

Or

```
dat %>%
   mutate_all(~ Recode(., "'A' = 1")) %>%
   head(5)
#  var1 var2
#1    B    C
#2    B    C
#3    B    C
#4    B    1
#5    C    C
```

Or even without the anonymous function call

```
dat %>%
   mutate_all(Recode, "'A' = 1") %>%
   head(5)
#  var1 var2
#1    B    C
#2    B    C
#3    B    C
#4    B    1
#5    C    C
```

Comment: So, when I pull up the help documentation via `?mutate_all` it doesn't show this.

Comment: @spindoctor I used dplyr 0.8.3

Comment: So am I. Reading the help documentation closely, I see at the end there is reference to a list argument, but not at the top of the document. Would it be appropriate to file an issue on the Github page for this? Or is this too low-level?

Comment: @spindoctor. I think it must be in the new features section where the function getting deprecated and replaced by new one.  I read it some time back